# Tunnel-SSH doesn't connect to server successful in node application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, networking, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to connect to a cloud server that runs my MongoDB from my local machine. I'm using [tunnel-ssh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tunnel-ssh) within the Node.js application I'm creating, however, I seem to have multiple problems and I don't fully understand what's going on.

**Problems**

1. I'm not 100% sure I'm successfully connecting to the server. There's no error, however, when I `console.log(server)` it says `_connections: 0,`. see full log below.
2. If I am connecting and then I try to run the `getDataFromMongoDB` function it returns the error, EADDRINUSE: address already in use 127.0.0.1:27000.

I've been trying to wrap my head around this all day and I'm not getting anywhere. Please help.

**Error 1 - Is server connecting**

```
Server {
  _events:
   [Object: null prototype] { connection: [Function], close: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 2,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _connections: 0,
  _handle:
   TCP {
     reading: false,
     onread: null,
     onconnection: [Function: onconnection],
     [Symbol(owner)]: [Circular] },
  _usingWorkers: false,
  _workers: [],
  _unref: false,
  allowHalfOpen: false,
  pauseOnConnect: false,
  _connectionKey: '4:127.0.0.1:27017',
  [Symbol(asyncId)]: 7 }
```

**Code**

```
var config = {
  username: "root",
  Password: "password on the server",
  host: "server IP address",
  port: 22,
  dstHost: "127.0.0.1",
  dstPort: 27017,
  localHost: "127.0.0.1",
  localPort: 27000
};

var tnl = tunnel(config, function(error, tnl) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  // yourClient.connect();
  // yourClient.disconnect();
  console.log(tnl);
  getDataFromMongoDB();
});

async function getDataFromMongoDB(page) {
  const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
  const uri = "mongodb://USRNAME:PASSWORD_FOR_MONGDB_DATABASE@localhost:27017";
  const client2 = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
  const client = await connectToMongodb(client2);
  const collection = client.db("my_database_name").collection("jobs");
  const jobs = await collection.find().toArray();
  console.log("jobs", jobs);
}

function connectToMongodb(client) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    client.connect(function(err) {
      console.log("connected", err);
      return resolve(client);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Well notably you are creating a "tunnel" with the `localPort` as `27000` but attempting to connect to `27017`. Pretty sure you don't want a "tunnel" going from localhost to localhost as well. Also the `connectToMongoDB` function here is pointless. Just do `const client = await MongoClient.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true })`. The `.connect()` static method was always here for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks @NeilLunn. Would you mind showing me the full working code. I'm new to this so I'm finding it a little confusing.

Comment: More than a little confused by what you are even attempting to do. IMHO, it is not the task of your application to set up it's own SSH tunnel, nor is it wise or appropriate to "one shot" connections to a database and then hang them up again. Your database connection *should* be active for the life-cycle of the application. And an SSH tunnel, *should* be a separate process invoked on the system in which the application is running.

Comment: That said, you have two basic errors. **1** Tunnel from localhost to localhost. You did not mean that, and almost certainly want a remote IP address in the "dstHost" which is the different computer running MongoDB. **2** In which case the `dstPort` is `27017`, and the `localPort` can be whatever you want, but your `MongoClient` connects to whatever the `localPort` is. Because that's how port forwarding works. And I guess **3**, if you did mean `localhost` to `localhost`, then forget it. Creating an SSH tunnel on the same system is pointless.

Comment: @NeilLunn Ahhh. Ok, by the sounds of it I'm way off. To give some more insight, I'm trying to grab some data from mongoDB on the cloud server before running my the application on my local machine using node. Is there another way I'm supposed to do this?  I'll also try to implement your suggestions.